# JQuery - Responsive Design (Display)

Tags: jquery, mobile, responsive-design

I'm trying to create my first RWD website, but now that I ve started writing the mobile CSS I think its the correct time to ask if where I'm heading is the correct way.

I wrote in html all media needed in order for the window to load the specific .css file (according to screen width desktop/tablet/mobile).

Desktop and tablet are pretty similar when it comes to design. Just few div rearrangements and it looks good. But when it comes to mobile I would like to change the look of navigator. 
For example in desktop its inline-block centered to the screen.
But on mobile I would like to have a kind of new design, a dropmenu lets say.

So I though of creating  both navigators within  html, and within JQuery write a code which will check the window.width. if the width will be smaller than tablet window.width (that would be 500px), then to add the display:none; to desktop-navigator and remove display: none; from mobile-navigator.

Q1:
  Is this the right way of doing it? code the divs in html and use JQ window.width to add/remove display? Or is there a better way? I 've tried to google this question but I couldnt find a straight answer.

Q2:
  here is my JQ code. Although it doesnt work for some reason, am I on the right path?

```
   checkWidth();

    $(window).resize(checkWidth);

     var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize < 500) {
           alert("works");
        //   $(".mobHome").removeClass("noShow");
        } else {
$(".mobHome").addClass("noShow");
}
     }
```

Comment: That's not the best approach. You should handle it all inside your CSS's `@media` queries. So actually you should use JS for event - traversing or animations that are usually not (or hardly) achievable by CSS alone. Anything other than that, should be defined by CSS. You don't want a browser to show an element, and than once JS parses the document make it disappear or do any other hardcore stuff. Instead hiding - showing elements within CSS is instantaneous - the user won't suffer from strange code behavior.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how to do that. but I guess its something between those lines: [code] '@media
 only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
 only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
 only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
 only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)
{

 #header {
  background-image: url(../images/banner_medium_2x.jpg);
  
 }
 
 #header a.logo{
  
  background-image: url(../images/logo_medium_2x.png); 
  
 }

}'[/code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this  in your css

```
@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
     .mobHome { display:block; }
}
@media screen and (min-width:551px) {
     .mobHome { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: he only needs one of those two - depending on the *mobile-first* approach.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I know what I need to do now. I just wasnt sure how to proceed. unfortunately I cant vote your comments yet. but each one had something that I needed to learn.  Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/)
It's a css and javascript framework with a mobile first approach.

To remove a certain div from display in bootstrap you could use their responsive utilities (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)
example:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    This is not visible on small screens.
</div>
<div class="visible-xs-block">
    This is only visible on small screens.
</div>
```

Bootstrap uses this to determine the sizes of xs, sm, md, ...

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: I ve read that bootstrap is good to use only if you want to use many functions from it. else its only getting the website heavier. ALthough I would like to learn how to use it at some point due to many comopanies requiring it in order to hire you

Comment: You can customize bootstrap, and only use the parts you need. Look at this page: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ For example, you could only check the grid system.

Comment: I will come back to this in few days. I want to create another website with bootstrap. Thank you for letting me know that this is possible. So far I only new about grids (I was using the 1200px.com)

Comment: oh, in that case, there is no reason why I shouldnt use bootstrap. I was misinformed for it. that will save me lot of time